# MongoDB C# driver sent to unspecified endpoints of replica set members

Tags: c#, mongodb, connection-string, mongodb-.net-driver

I had 3 nodes of mongodb replicaset, for example 
Primary: `localhost:27017`, Secondaries: `localhost:27018` and `localhost:27019`.
I passed to mongodb driver connection string `mongodb://localhost:27019,localhost:27017/admin?readPreference=secondaryPreferred`

BUT when I trace requests I catch that mongodb driver sends part of requests to node `localhost:27018` which not specified in connection string.
How to prevent sending requests to unspecified nodes?

Comment: try using `directConnection=true` connection string option